# Spring Boot Data JPA receive Multiple Out Parameters from stored procedure

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to call stored procedure with multiple out parameters via Spring Boot Data JPA (v2.2.6), but receive an error:

```
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger: {call TEST_SP(?,?,?)}
RACE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [DOC_NAME] as [VARCHAR] - [ololo]
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: DOC_ID; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: DOC_ID] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: DOC_ID
```

Stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_SP]
    @DOC_ID bigint output,
    @DOC_GUID nvarchar(255) output,
    @DOC_NAME nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @DOC_ID = 6666, @DOC_GUID = @DOC_NAME
END
```

Here my entity (it is not related to SP):

```
@Data
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "SomeEntity.test", procedureName = "TEST_SP", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "DOC_ID", type = Long.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "DOC_GUID", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "DOC_NAME", type = String.class)
})
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT_DATA")
public class SomeEntity {
    // some variables
}
```

Here my repository:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {

    @Procedure(name = "SomeEntity.test")
    Map<String, Object> testSp(@Param("DOC_NAME") String docName);
}
```

Here how I call it:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("test")
    String test() {
        return repository.testSp("ololo").toString();
    }
}
```

As example I used these links: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/sample/User.java#L77
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/e27933455efa6d1821dea23abd2bbe109b5d59a7/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L362

**Upd:** I've tried with Oracle 11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp(x OUT INTEGER, y OUT INTEGER) AS
BEGIN
  x := 17; y := 93;
END;


@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "EstatementsDataEntity.test", procedureName = "test_sp", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "x", type = Integer.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "y", type = Integer.class)
})
```

But receive almost identical error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find working solution with annotations and submitted a bug [DATAJPA-1722](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1722)

But I could managed to solve issue using `EntityManager`:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    void callStoredProcedureUsingEntitiManager() {
        StoredProcedureQuery proc = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("test_sp");
        proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("x", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter("y", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        proc.execute();
        assertThat(proc.getOutputParameterValue("x")).isEqualTo(17);
        assertThat(proc.getOutputParameterValue("y")).isEqualTo(93);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any updates on the solution with @Procedure annotation?

Answer (score 4):

FYI for anyone still using older versions of Spring Boot. This error was caused by calling a procedure without enclosing it in a transaction. Error message was a bit of a red herring but the fix was to add @Transaction to the caller.

In the example above I'd include a service layer class between Controller and SomeRepository and annotate my service layer method as transactional.

i.e.

```
@Service
public class SomeService{
    
    @Autowired
    SomeRepository someRepo;

    @Transactional
    public Map<String, Object> testSp(String docName){
        return someRepo.testSp(docName);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is a problem for newer versions too. You must use `@Transactional` when calling a stored procedure

Comment: for the solution for calling postgresql procedures with in/out parameters.