# Spring Boot invalidDataAccessApiUsageException - OUT/INOUT Parameter is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oracle10g, java-stored-procedures

i'm using an Oracle stored procedure in Spring Boot which has some IN/OUT parameters.

When i'm getting an out parameter it throws an exception `invalidDataAccessApiUsageException: OUT/INOUT Parameter is not available: ent_mensaje.`

This is the stored procedure definition

```
create or replace PROCEDURE     fon_anula_programacion (
   ent_numero_operacion   IN       NUMBER,
   ent_numero_fisico      IN       VARCHAR2,
   ent_mensaje            IN OUT   VARCHAR2,
   ent_canal_origen       IN OUT   VARCHAR2,
   ent_senal_proceso      IN OUT   VARCHAR2,
   ent_senal_commit       IN OUT   VARCHAR2,
   ent_sw_pos             IN OUT   NUMBER
) IS
...
```

Entity class whit its @NamedStoredProcedureQuery

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Valores.AnularAdicionFondoSif",
                procedureName = "FON.FON_ANULA_PROGRAMACION",
                resultClasses = DTOAnularAdicionSIF.class,
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "ent_numero_operacion", type = BigDecimal.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "ent_numero_fisico", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "ent_mensaje", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "ent_canal_origen", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "ent_senal_proceso", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "ent_senal_commit", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "ent_sw_pos", type = BigDecimal.class, mode = ParameterMode.INOUT)
                }
        )
})
public class DTOAnularAdicionSIF {
    @Id
    @Column
    private BigDecimal Numero_operacion;
    @Column
    private String Numero_fisico;
    @Column
    private String Mensaje;
    @Column
    private String Canal_origen;
    @Column
    private String Senal_proceso;
    @Column
    private String Senal_commit;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal Sw_pos;
}
```

My Params class

```
public class AnularAdicionSIFParameters {
    @Params(name = "ent_numero_operacion",direction = Params.Direction.IN)
    private BigDecimal Numero_operacion;

    @Params(name = "ent_numero_fisico",direction = Params.Direction.IN)
    private String Numero_fisico;

    @Params(name = "ent_mensaje",direction = Params.Direction.INOUT)
    private String Mensaje;

    @Params(name = "ent_canal_origen",direction = Params.Direction.INOUT)
    private String Canal_origen;

    @Params(name = "ent_senal_proceso",direction = Params.Direction.INOUT)
    private String Senal_proceso;

    @Params(name = "ent_senal_commit",direction = Params.Direction.INOUT)
    private String Senal_commit;

    @Params(name = "ent_sw_pos",direction = Params.Direction.INOUT)
    private BigDecimal Sw_pos;
}
```

Sending parameters

```
AnularAdicionSIFParameters anularAdicionSIFParameters = AnularAdicionSIFParameters.builder()
.Numero_operacion(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(comprobante)))
                .Numero_fisico(numerofisico)
                .Senal_commit("S")
                .Canal_origen(canal)
                .Senal_proceso("S")
                .Mensaje("")
                .Sw_pos(BigDecimal.valueOf(0))
                .build();
String response = repository.AnularAdicionReturnMensaje(anularAdicionSIFParameters);
```

Repository method

```
public String AnularAdicionReturnMensaje(AnularAdicionSIFParameters parameters) throws IllegalAccessException{
        String name_procedure = "Valores.AnularAdicionFondoSif";
//super is the class who set the parameters and execute the procedure
        ResponseProcedure<AnularAdicionSIF> respuestaSif = super.runNamedStoredProcedure(name_procedure,parameters);
        return respuestaSif.getOutput().get("ent_mensaje").toString();
    }
```

Setting the parameters and executing the procedure

```
public ResponseProcedure<E> runNamedStoredProcedure(String nameProcedure, Object params) throws IllegalAccessException {
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(nameProcedure);
        Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<>();

        Class<?> objectClass = params.getClass();

        Field[] extend = objectClass.getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] base = objectClass.getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] allFields = new Field[extend.length + base.length];
        Arrays.setAll(allFields, i ->
                (i < extend.length ? extend[i] : base[i - extend.length]));


        for (Field field: allFields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Params.class)) {
                Params param = field.getAnnotation(Params.class);
                if(param.direction() == Params.Direction.IN || param.direction() == Params.Direction.INOUT)
                    storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(param.name(), (field.get(params) != null ) ? field.get(params) : "");
            }
        }

        storedProcedureQuery.execute();

        Arrays.stream(allFields).filter(field -> (field.getAnnotation(Params.class).direction() == Params.Direction.OUT || field.getAnnotation(Params.class).direction() == Params.Direction.INOUT))
                .forEach(ff ->{
                    Params param = ff.getAnnotation(Params.class);
                    output.put(param.name(), storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(param.name()));
                });

        return new ResponseProcedure<E>(toList(storedProcedureQuery.getResultList()), output);
    }
```

And the error: `OUT/INOUT parameter not available: ent_mensaje; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: ent_mensaje`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed by adding @Transactional to the method that performs the call to repository. like [@Parawata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17551704/parawata) comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70169083/9310852)