# When is @Transactional required when calling a stored procedure?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have SQL Server stored procedure as follows:

```sql
procedure [dbo].[perf] (
  @endDate date,
  @startDate date,
  @productName varchar(20),
  @endPrice decimal(10,2) output,
  @startPrice decimal(10,2) output,
  @startEv decimal(10,3) output,
  @endEv decimal(10,3) output) as 

BEGIN 

--TSQL code

END
```

If I call this method without @Transactional:

```java
public interface PriceRepository extends Repository<Price, Long> {

    @Procedure(name = "Price.perf")
    Map<String, Object> getStartPrice(@Param("endDate") LocalDate endDate, @Param("startDate") LocalDate startDate, @Param("productName") String productName);
    
}
```

I get the following error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: OUT/INOUT
> parameter not available: endPrice

If I annotate `getStartPrice` with `@Transactional`, it works without error as noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70959567/1706691). Why and when is it necessary to make the call transactional?

**Update**

It appears all stored procedures must be called with @Transactional. If the stored procedure just ends with `return`:

```sql
procedure [dbo].[perf] (
  @endDate date,
  @startDate date,
  @productName varchar(20),
  @endPrice decimal(10,2) output,
  @startPrice decimal(10,2) output,
  @startEv decimal(10,3) output,
  @endEv decimal(10,3) output) as 

BEGIN 

--TSQL code
  
  return
END
```

then @Transactional can be on the `Repository` method. Without it, you get the error as I noted above. However, if the stored procedure ends with a `select`:

```sql
procedure [dbo].[perf] (
  @endDate date,
  @startDate date,
  @productName varchar(20),
  @endPrice decimal(10,2) output,
  @startPrice decimal(10,2) output,
  @startEv decimal(10,3) output,
  @endEv decimal(10,3) output) as 

BEGIN 

--TSQL code
  
  select * from someTable;
END
```

Then you must use `@Transactional` on some method calling the repository method. If you don't use `@Transactional` though, you get a more descriptive error stating:

> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
> You're trying to execute a @Procedure method without a surrounding
> transaction that keeps the connection open so that the ResultSet can
> actually be consumed; Make sure the consumer code uses @Transactional
> or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction

Why do these differences exist depending on how the stored procedure ends?

Comment: Can you share the code where you call the repository method?

Comment: @times29 - An example call to the repository method is `repository.getStartPrice(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now(), "testProduct");`

Answer (score 0):

[According to Vlad Mihalcea, a Hibernate maintainer](https://vladmihalcea.com/best-way-call-stored-procedure-jpa-hibernate/), after calling a stored procedure

> by default, the CallableStatement is closed upon ending the currently running database transaction, either via calling commit or rollback.

This means that without a wrapping transaction, the underlying `CallableStatement` of the prepared statement could remain open which is bad from a resource usage view and if Oracle is used, it can even lead to [ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01000) issues.

Citing Vlad Mihalcea:

> Releasing the underlying JDBC CallableStatement as soon as possible is very important when calling a stored procedure with JPA and Hibernate, as otherwise, the database cursors will be open until the current transaction is committed or rolled back.

That is the reason why you should wrap the code that is calling the procedure with `@Transactional`. If it fixes another exception in your code - even better!

Answer (score 0):

When writing the same code in JDBC, you don't need to wrap calls to read-only  procedures into transaction, and Statement is a Closeable and putting it in a try-with-resource will auto close it.
So the only logical conclusion is that the need of wrapping into a transaction when using the interface Repository is due to the layer cake of calls introduced by Spring and Hibernate to do the same job, complicating how the results are given back to the original caller because the code creating the proxy based on the Repository interface has no way to know how the caller will consume the data. The only thing the JDBC layer can tell is that there is a ResultSet pending to be consumed or not (hence the difference of behavior with "return" or ending with a "select..." with MS-SQLServer or DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cursor) and "? := cursor;" with ORACLE).